# How to display custom content on a custom endpoint

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, endpoint

In the plugin related to WooCommerce at the following address:
[enter link description here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-affiliates/)

The Plugin: YITH WooCommerce Affiliates
I want to add an endpoint to the dashboard menu.
I want to use this section as advertising tools such as placing banners.
I added the following line to the class-yith-wcaf-endpoints.php file.

```
'banners' => _x( 'Banners', '[GLOBAL] Endpoint title', 'yith-woocommerce-affiliates' ),
```

I also saved the Permalink Settings again to fix the 404 error.
With this, the banners item was added to the dashboard menu. Then I created a file called dashboard-banners.php in the templates/shortcodes path and put the following code in it.

```
    <?php
/**
 * Affiliate Banners
 *
 * @author YITH
 * @package YITH\Affiliates\Templates
 * @version 2.0.0
 */

/**
 * Template variables:
 *
 * @var $affiliate      YITH_WCAF_Affiliate
 * @var $generated_url  string
 * @var $original_url   string
 * @var $share_enabled  bool
 * @var $atts           array
 * @var $share_atts     array
 */

if ( ! defined( 'YITH_WCAF' ) ) {
    exit;
} // Exit if accessed directly
?>

<?php
do_action( 'yith_wcaf_before_dashboard_section', 'banners', $atts );
?>
<div>
    <h1>Welcome to the Banners endpoint!</h1>
</div>
<?php
do_action( 'yith_wcaf_after_dashboard_section', 'banners', $atts );
```

Now I want the custom content that I put in the dashboard-banners.php file to be displayed at the endpoint of the banners.
I appreciate any help and guidance.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while but this worked for me-

```
add_action('init', function () {
    add_rewrite_endpoint('my-coins', EP_PERMALINK);
});

add_action('init', function () {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^my-coins/?$',
        'index.php?my-coins=true',
        'top'
    );
});

add_filter('request', function ($vars) {
    if(isset($vars['my-coins'])) {
        $vars['my-coins'] = true;
    }

    return $vars;
});

function load_custom_endpoint_content()
{
    if (get_query_var('my-coins')) {
        echo 'Hello, World!';
        // include get_template_directory() . '/custom-template.php';
        exit;
    }
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'load_custom_endpoint_content');
```

1. Add the url
2. Add the rule to catch the endpoint on page load
3. Add the query var into WP's query var list
4. Load the content